# How to design software when using BDD?

Tags: design, uml, development-methodologies, bdd

I'm working on a project right now and it's my first project using [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development). Up till now, the user stories have proven themselves a very valuable weapon to understand requirements and to specify the solution in a comprehensive, easy to understand language.

My question is this: now that my user stories are complete, how do I design my solution? I understand that I derive behavior tests from my user stories, and I have to do UI design, but am I supposed to use good ol' UML? I'm under the impression that when using user stories, UML is left out; is this correct?

Comment: You might want to provide a link to a definition of BDD or even state outright what BDD is in your question!  My first hit searching on Google is not Behavior Driven Development, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to Behavior-Driven Development. :)

Comment: user stories show `what` to do , uml shows `how` you do it. long story short: you need both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general userstories are requirements from the customer point of view that most of the time say what to implement (= features) but not how to do it (design, workflow).

If you want to create a new app out of nothing (greenfield-soulution) in a agile/scrum-like manner out of existing userstories i would suggest this workflow:

- bring the userstories into an implementition order to find out which story to implement first. Start with stories that have as least dependencies to other stories as possible and that have most business-value. For details see [StoryMaps-The new user story backlog is a map](http://www.agileproductdesign.com/blog/the_new_backlog.html)
- implement the first userstory as [nesteted bdd/tdd loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957847/should-bdd-be-automated-with-unit-tests-integration-tests-or-both/5968522#5968522)

Comment: So, with the user stories I build a map detailing order and interactions, then I make UML diagrams as needed, and then I start building my tests. Am I getting this right?

Comment: i am not shure if you realy need uml diagrams. most of my projects lived happyly without them.